# Using DLLImport With IIS/IIS Express Relative Paths

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, dll, iis-7

I have a VS2013 solution with various projects. The primary application is a MVC website and the other projects are all supporting functions separated for organization. The MVC project references each of these other projects and one project in particular references a 3rd party DLL using DLLImport. Up until now a static path has been defined and any server we deploy to must have a folder with that DLL in it.

```
[DllImport("C:\hiding.dll")]
```

I want to optimize it so that I can just include "hiding.dll" in the \bin folder of the project during publish but the DllImport fails when I try to specify a relative path. My guess is I'm expecting the relative path to be something different than what it is. Debugging with IIS Express and Production with IIS yield the same results, "Unable to Load DLL."

I don't know much about pathing in IIS Express debug mode, but in production this is what the folder looks like.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hiding.dll (this is where VS2013 publish puts it which I know is wrong)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\hiding.dll (so I copied it here)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\iReferenceHiding.dll
```

The iReferenceHiding.dll does what it says. It is the DLL compiled from one of the projects of the solution that actually does the DLLImport call.

I've found tons of information on where DLL's get stored during run time and everything seems to point to \bin being the first folder that should be checked. My question ultimately boils down to **"How do I include this 3rd party DLL in my VS2013 MVC application so what when I publish it to IIS (or even debug using IIS Express) the DLL is found?"** (Again an absolute path works like a champ).

I appreciate everyone's time.

**UPDATE**

IIS in production is pulling from the path: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv". So the relative path will work so long as the DLL is copied here. I have no idea why it doesn't check the \bin folder first. My only guess is that with IIS, this is where the application is loaded from and not the IIS inetpub directory.

IIS Express (while debugging) loads from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express" but placing the dll here doesn't help. I have no idea where this is loading from.

At this point it looks like a post build event to move the DLL to a static location and use the absolute path is my only option.

Comment: As a side-note, your absolute-path won't work because you're using unescaped backslashes. You must use either `"C:\\hiding.dll"` or `@"C:\hiding.dll` (verbatim string).

Comment: Do you have the "Copy to Output Directory" property set on the DLL file in Solution Explorer? Or if you don't want the file in your project you can set the copy operation as a custom Post-Build Step in your Project Properties page.

Comment: @Dai - On your first note I had just hand typed that line and failed to escape the characters. In the code I am escaping them.

Comment: @Dai To your second question, I do have the "Copy if newer" option set. Its actually copying to a directory above the bin folder, but that's a minor inconvenience for now. The bigger problem is getting the DLL to where that relative path is looking.